# Jquery mobile:overlapping text on clicking back button

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am developing an app in jquery mobile.The issue I have is, on clicking the back button the text is showing as overlapped(one on the other).On moving forward through various list views there is no such issue,problem is while traversing backwards via "back" button.The issue is observed in browser also.

In the app by default the content gets populated on mobile init event whose result is a ul-li list.On clicking each 'li's a new 'ul''li' string is generated via onclick event which is appended to page container. The code for generating new page is as follows

```
var moviePage = $("<div data-role='page' data-url='itemList' data-theme='c'><div data-role='navbar'  class='myCorner' data-corner='left 10px' ></div><div data-role='header' data-theme='f'><a href='#' data-rel='back'  data-transition='slide' data-theme='a' data-direction='reverse' data-icon='back'>"+manufListName+"</a><h1>"
         + itemModelName +"</h1>"+"</div>"+"<br>"+"<div data-role='content'>"+"<ul data-role='listview' data-inset='false' data-theme='c'>"+itemList+" </ul></div></div>");

moviePage.appendTo( $.mobile.pageContainer );

$.mobile.changePage(moviePage);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: use this method for generating pages http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/9jc8Y/ you might have a problem with the way you generate new pages.

Comment: @Omar sililar method itself is used

Comment: try this code `$(document).on('swipeleft swiperight', '[data-role=page]', function () {
    $.mobile.changePage($.mobile.activePage.prev('[data-role=page]'));
});` using swipe instead of back button and check if the problem persists.